# Does center of mass change in a complex rigid body if an element with negligible mass is removed?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics, inertia

If you are given an object composed of a sphere with two cylinders attached to opposite sides, and one cylinder is removed (cylinders has negligible mass) would the center of mass change?

Comment: In what way is the mass of the cylinders negligible?

Comment: If the cylinder has any mass it is not negligible to the exact COM

Comment: I suppose a negligible mass does not contribute to the center of mass, by definition. Otherwise, it wouldn't be negligible.

Answer (score 3):

An exact calculation will always tell you that the center of mass changed. Whether that change is negligible depends on what your measure of negligible is.

The further apart the centers of mass of the cylinder and the rest of the object are, the more the center of mass of the combined object will shift by removing the cylinder. Explicitly, using the definition of the center of mass, the shift is

$$ \Delta r = \frac{m d}{M+m}$$

where $d$ is the distance between the two centers of mass (of the still attached cylinder and the rest), $m$ is the mass of the cylinder, and $M$ is the mass of the object without the cylinder.